# ASPNETCOMPILERERROR - object reference not set to an instance of object

Tags: asp.net

I am getting ASPNETCOMPILERERROR while publishing a web project.

This project is in .net 4.0 and we are publishing in VS2012.

Build is getting succeeded, but while publishing we are getting following error

ASPNETCOMPILERERROR - object reference not set to an instance of object.

Please let us know how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you install VS2012 update 1?

Comment: Yes i have installed VS2012 Update1 still it is not working.

Comment: even i have downgraded to VS2010 in another system and tried to publishing it is giving same error.

Comment: Whether other system with VS 2010 has .net 4.5 installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the issue.

One of the dll causing reference issue, but build is getting succeed.

Solved by following these steps

1. Checked in the temporary folder(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files) where VS Creates dlls for each page( i have opted for individual assemblies while publishing)
2. Before creating dlls, it generates .Compiled files and then converts each file to a dll.
3. we found one of the page is not getting converted to dll, instead it created a file with .delete extension and halted.
4. Now we ran our application from VS and tried open the page which is not able getting converted to dll.
5. Now we got the issue as an exception.

Hope this will help some one else.

Comment: how to select opted for individual assemblies while publishing